# DevExpress WinForms GridView sorting work wrong

Tags: winforms, sorting, gridview, devexpress

Sorting work wrong after update DevExpress v10 to v15
I mean when I use default sorting it sorting and displaying wrong and dont sort my collection
I use **BindingList< IUser>** as binding collection

This one is default list
[BindingList items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpE01.png)
On GridView looks good

But if I will sort by this column first it will sort wrong like
[GridView items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFhkQ.png)
And my BindingList items didn't sort

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide details for what you mean by *"it sort and displaying wrong"*

Comment: Thanks I added something - If you need more just ask what details you need

Comment: Data source (`BindingList` in your case) doesn't matter because DevEx grid uses own separate filtering/sorting, i.e. will never sort your list. But I have to admit that second screenshot looks strange. Probably you should post this in their support channel.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress (using v15.1.5 myself) has a FilterMode option on each Column which is set to "Value" by default. Changing it to "DisplayText" may solve your problem.

If this doesn't solve your problem, try to overrie the ToString()-Method in your IUser class to return the username.

Comment: I have v15.2 DevExpress. 
And I found trouble - it sorting right but displaying wrong